# Error on command: service: "ecmascript"

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have sucessfully run locator commands in Firefox, Chrome and IE but I have an issue with **Opera 12.02**.
This code is the source of the issue:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_txtUserLog")).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
//entering values to a username field
```

I got the following error in console:

```
com.opera.core.systems.scope.exceptions.CommunicationException: Error on command:
service: "ecmascript" commandID: 2 format: 0status:tag: 32 payload: "\n%Unknown error while executing command"
```

I am newbie to Selenium Webdriver, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3837/error-on-command-service-ecmascript